# netty ssl connection with android 2.3.4

Tags: java, android, ssl, netty

I need to make an application on a device (vr100 casio), who run on android2.3.4
I tested my code on a samsung galaxy tab running with android 6.0.1

The program consist in establishing a longpolling asynchronous SSL connection.
I am using netty. I already tried using one of the last version 4.1.0, with no success (more precisly this is working on galaxy tab but not on android 2.3.4 device).
I also tried downgraded netty to 3.2.0. for the needs of this project I am using android API 10 2.3.3.

I know that the connection is establishing and the program working without SSL but as soon as the SSL layer is enabled, nothing happens.

my client.java :

```
Bootstrap b= new Bootstrap();
NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
b.group(workerGroup);
b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);

        b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

                SslContext sslCtx = null;
                try {
                    sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient().build();
                } catch (SSLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Journal.e(TAG, "constructionsslCI", e.getMessage());
                }

                pipeline.addLast("ssl", sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), SERVEUR, PORT));
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpRequestEncoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new ClientHandler(SERVEUR, ch));
            }
        });

        doConnect(b);
    }

    private static void doConnect(final Bootstrap b) {
        b.connect(IP, PORT).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                    doConnect(b);
                }
                else {
                    future.channel().closeFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                            doConnect(b);
                        }});}}});}}
```

**I am sending the message like this:**

```
while(devicesProvider.getChannel().isActive()==false && devicesProvider.getChannel().isWritable()==false){
}

final ChannelFuture writeFuture =devicesProvider.getChannel().writeAndFlush(request);
writeFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        if(!writeFuture.isSuccess()){
            writeFuture.cause().printStackTrace();
        }} });
```